# How to make a pdf file with node js using a custom font from a local file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, pdf, fonts

I tried all library and tricks possibles, I tested everything found on the web, but nothing worked so... I need to make a pdf file with node js using a custom font from a local file. The font format is otf. Nothing more to tell you :x

Comment: Oh, no, you have _lots_ more to tell us. You say you tried all of them, so: that's quite a lot, can you please list each one you tried, and show how you tried to use it, and how that didn't work for you? Otherwise we'll have nothing to recommend: you already tried everything.

Answer (score 0):

To generate PDF file from Node.js, I can advise you to do it from a HTML template.

To do this, I'm using this library: [phantom-html-to-pdf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/phantom-html-to-pdf).

Here is an example of usage :

```
const fs = require('fs');
const htmlTopdf = require('phantom-html-to-pdf')();

let html = fs.readFileSync('./template.html');
htmlTopdf({html: html}, function(err, pdf) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
    else {
        pdf.stream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('./destination.pdf'));
    }
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Js `const fs = require('fs')
const htmlTopdf = require('phantom-html-to-pdf')()

let html = fs.readFileSync('./template.html')
htmlTopdf({html: html}, function(err, pdf) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
    else {
        pdf.stream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('./output.pdf'))
        console.log('pdf created')
    }
})`

Comment: Html `<html>
    <body>   
        <style>
        @font-face {
            font-family: "Axis";
            src: url("./fonts/Axis Extrabold.otf")
        }
        body {
            font-family: "Axis";
        }
        </style>
        test
    </body>
</html>`
The webpage displays correctly but the pdf is blank
Seems like ur french like me we could speak french nu ?